# previous_post_link in same taxonomy in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, pagination

I'm trying to make `previous_post_link()` and `next_post_link()` work inside a custom post type, inside a same category (taxonomy) but its not working.

It this posible ?

I'm trying:

```
<?php previous_post_link('<div class="posts-next">%link</div>', 'Next in category',TRUE); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a plugin for this. `next_post_link` and `previous_post_link` will use the category taxonomy (literally)*, so they will not work as expected with custom taxonomies, which I think you are using here.

I've used both [Smarter Navigation](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/smarter-navigation/) by Scribu and [Ambrosite Next/Previous Post Link Plus](http://www.ambrosite.com/plugins/next-previous-post-link-plus-for-wordpress), which are both great plugins for this sort of thing.

**See the source for `get_adjacent_post()` which is used by WP's `next/previous_post` functions in \wp-includes\link-template.php to see how "category" is hard-coded.*

Answer (score 1):

The taxonomy is no longer hardcoded for `next_post_link` and `previous_post_link` you just need to specify it in the last parameter

```
<?php next_post_link( $format, $link, $in_same_term = false, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = 'category' ); ?>
```

[See documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link)